# unsure why state is changing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have a button in a child component for debugging purposes that prints the current state in its parent component. When it prints, that is how I want the state to be. When I hit another button in the same child component, the state changes in the parent, by removing a few properties.

Notice how the `Id` and `SEO_CSEO_Survey_Questions__r` properties are now missing.

[image]

Child Component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router';

class Index extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      selected: 'created'
    }

    this.updatePreview = this.updatePreview.bind(this);
    this.renderEditArea = this.renderEditArea.bind(this);
  }

  isActive(value) {
      return 'slds-tabs--default__item '+((value===this.state.selected) ?'slds-active':'');
  }

  updatePreview(e){
    const updatedPreview = {
      ...this.props.selectedPreview,
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    };
    this.props.update(updatedPreview)
  }

  // determines which type of edit area should display
  // survey settings or question
  renderEditArea() {
    let selected = this.props.selectedPreview;
    let hasNameKey = "Name" in selected;
    if(hasNameKey){
      return (
        <div>
          <input
            onChange={(e) => this.updatePreview(e)}
            name="Name"
            type="text"
            className="slds-input"
            value={selected.Name ? selected.Name : ''}
          />
          <input
            onChange={(e) => this.updatePreview(e)}
            name="SEO__Welcome_Text__c"
            type="text"
            className="slds-input"
            value={selected.SEO__Welcome_Text__c ? selected.SEO__Welcome_Text__c : ''}
          />
        </div>
      )
    }else {
      return (
        <input
          onChange={(e) => this.updatePreview(e)}
          name="SEO__Question__c"
          type="text"
          className="slds-input"
          value={selected.SEO__Question__c ? selected.SEO__Question__c : ''}
        />
      )
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="slds-size--1-of-1 slds-medium-size--4-of-5 slds-large-size--4-of-5">
        <div className="slds-tabs--default">
          <h2 className="slds-text-heading--small slds-p-top--x-small" style={{position: "absolute"}}>
            <button onClick={this.props.addQuestion} className="slds-button slds-button--icon slds-p-left--xx-small" title="add sur">
              <svg className="slds-button__icon slds-button__icon--medium" aria-hidden="true">
                <use xlinkHref={addIcon}></use>
              </svg>
              <span className="slds-assistive-text">Add Question</span>
            </button>
          </h2>
          <ul className="slds-tabs--default__nav" style={{justifyContent: "flex-end"}}>
            <Link to="/"className="slds-button slds-button--neutral">Back</Link>
            <button onClick={this.props.save} className="slds-button slds-button--brand">Save</button>
            <button onClick={this.props.currentState} className="slds-button slds-button--brand">Current State</button>            
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div className="slds-grid slds-wrap slds-grid--pull-padded">
          {this.renderEditArea()}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Index;
```

Parent

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { getQuestions, addQuestion, deleteQuestion, newSurveyQuestions, updateSurveyQuestions, EMPTY_SURVEY } from './helpers';

import SideBar from './survey/SideBar';
import MainArea from './survey/Index';

class Survey extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      survey: [],
      selectedPreview: []
    }

    this.componentWillMount = this.componentWillMount.bind(this);
    this.save = this.save.bind(this);
    this.setSelectedPreview = this.setSelectedPreview.bind(this);
    this.currentState = this.currentState.bind(this);
  }

  // if the url is `/survey/new`, create an empty survey
  // to save for later.
  // else if there is an id in the url, load the survey and questions
  componentWillMount(){
    if(this.props.pathname === "/survey/new") {
      this.setState({
        survey: EMPTY_SURVEY,
        selectedPreview: EMPTY_SURVEY[0]
      })
    } else if (this.props.params.surveyId){
      getQuestions(this.props.params.surveyId).then(survey => {
        // 'survey' contains all the questions
        this.setState({
          survey,
          selectedPreview: survey[0]
        });
      });
    }
  }

  currentState() {
    console.log('clicking Current State');
    console.log(this.state.survey[0]);
  }

  // saves a new survey with associated newly created questions
  // or saves an existing survey with associated questions
  save() {
    console.log('clicking Save');
    console.log(this.state.survey[0]);
    // if the url is set to survey/new
    // save new survey with associated newly created questions
    if(this.props.pathname === "/survey/new") {
      newSurveyQuestions(this.state.survey).then( id => {
        this.context.router.transitionTo(`/survey/id/${id}`);
      })

    // else update survey and questions
    } else {
      updateSurveyQuestions(this.state.survey);
    }
  }

  // sets selectedPreview for the entire component and
  // its children
  setSelectedPreview(selectedPreview) {
    this.setState({selectedPreview});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="slds-grid slds-wrap slds-grid--pull-padded">
        <SideBar
          survey={this.state.survey}
          setSelectedPreview={this.setSelectedPreview}
          deleteQuestion={this.deleteQuestion}

        />
        <MainArea
          addQuestion={this.addQuestion}
          selectedPreview={this.state.selectedPreview}
          update={this.update}
          save={this.save}
          currentState={this.currentState}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

Survey.contextTypes = {
  router: React.PropTypes.object
}

export default Survey;
```

help function

```
export function updateSurveyQuestions(survey) {
  // create proper url for update request
  const requestURL = `${URL + survey[0].attributes.url}`;

  // save questions for later update requests
  const questions = survey[0].SEO__CSEO_Survey_Questions__r.records;

  let s = [...survey];

  // remove properties for proper body format
  delete s[0].Id;
  delete s[0].SEO__CSEO_Survey_Questions__r;
  delete s[0].attributes;

  axios.patch(requestURL, s[0], API_TOKEN);

  questions.forEach( question => {
    // save request url for later
    let requestURL = `${URL + question.attributes.url }`;

    // remove properites for proper body format
    delete question.attributes;
    delete question.Id;

    axios.patch(requestURL, question, API_TOKEN);
  })
}
```

When I removed all the code in `save()`, except for the `console.log`'s, it prints as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr:** Your code is working fine. What you are seeing is a consequence of how objects and the console work. Do

```
console.log(this.state.survey[0].Id);
```

instead to see that the property does actually exist.

See also [Is Chrome's JavaScript console lazy about evaluating arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4057440/218196)

---

> When I removed all the code in save(), except for the console.log's, it prints as expected.

That seems to suggest that that code is changing the object. E.g. `updateSurveyQuestions` or `newSurveyQuestions` might remove these properties.

You have to keep in mind that the output you see in the console is computed at the moment you *expand the properties*, **not** at the moment `console.log` is called. In fact, the little `i` icon next to `Object` tells you that. When you hover over it says:

> Value below was evaluated just now

Here is a simplified example of what you are experiencing: Expand the object and notice that it is empty even though we removed it *after* calling `console.dir` (open your browser's console):

```js
var obj = {foo: 42};
console.dir(obj);
delete obj.foo;
```

---

Ideally `updateSurveyQuestions` or `newSurveyQuestions` would not mutate the object directly, but rather clone it, make the necessary changes to the clone and then update the components state (if desired). E.g. a simple way to clone the object is via `Object.assign`:

```
var copy = Object.assign({}, this.state.survey[0]);
```

Comment: It looks like `updateSurveyQuestions` and `newSurveyQuestions` are mutating the object directly, which I don't understand because I'm passing a copy of state to it, correct?

Comment: *"because I'm passing a copy of state to it"* All I can see is that you are passing `this.state.survey`, which is not a copy. JavaScript represents objects (arrays are objects too) as *references*. They are *not* copied on assignment.

Comment: I create copy of state like so, `let survey = [...this.state.survey]`, and passed `survey` into my functions. still getting same error.

Comment: That only creates an copy of the array itself, but not the objects inside the array. I.e. `survey[0] === this.state.survey[0]`.

Comment: I know. In my helper functions I work with the array accordingly.

Comment: What's strange is my state is being changed as well, even though I'm not setting state in my helper functions. This is breaking my code since the properties `Id` and `SEO_CSEO_Survey_Questions__r` are required in other parts of my web app.

Comment: As I have said, you would have to make a *copy* of the object you are going to change.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139615/discussion-between-tyler-zika-and-felix-kling).